# How can one determine the key characteristics of a solar cell from the $I$-$V$ curve?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, solar-cells

I have recently measured the $I$-$V$ characteristics of several $\rm Si$ solar cell samples and am now attempting to extract the series resistance $R_S$; parallel resistance $R_P$; open circuit voltage $V_{OC}$; short circuit current $I_{SC}$ and fill factor.

From what I have read, I understand that $V_{OC}$ is the voltage across the cell, for zero current flow and $I_{SC}$ the current flowing for zero voltage across the cell. Fill factor is the ratio of IV at maximum power production to the product of $I_{SC}$ and $V_{OC}$. I am, however, struggling to determine these values from my data (one example of the plotted data is shown below, please note that the orders of magnitude on the axis are off); all other IV graphs I have seen, have had a very different appearance, starting from a plateau at $I_{SC}$, before decaying down into $V_{OC}$, allowing both to be easily determined, as well as the fill factor.

[image: I-V curve for varying levels of illumination]

I also understand that $R_S$ is to be found from the ln(I)-V curve, by finding the variation between the high-current section of the graph and the best fit of linear mid-current section and then plotting this voltage deviation against I, whereupon the gradient yields $R_S$ (see below graph).

[image: Construction line to determine voltage difference between linear continuation and actual data.]

$R_P$ is to be found by taking the inverse gradient of the linear portion of the I-V plot approaching zero voltage.

My question, so to speak, is whether my above stated understandings are correct and also how to extract the fill factor,$V{OC}$ and $I{SC}$ from my graph.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be able to see Isc, Rshunt, FF, Voc etc. if you magnify the part of graph 1 with just current < 0. It looks like the device has a high series resistance and most of the graph is above I=0. For  the log plot you can determine how the Rs is affecting the performance by determining how the curve deviates from tour straight line as the current rises. You can read up more at this site https://www.pveducation.org/pvcdrom/characterisation/dark-iv-measurements